# Guest access through hotspots (proxies with a ToS to accept) don't consistently work

Tags: proxy, authentication, web, guest, content-filter

I've noticed that certain websites (Facebook) don't reliably initiate a hotspot login when compared to others (google.com).  In other words, when a user connects for the first time to a hotspot they are asked to login or accept a terms of service (ToS).

If a user tries to go to Facebook, then the page hangs and no redirection occurs.  Conversely, if they go to Google, then the authentication page pops up immediately.

I have found this pattern consistent with many implementations (Starbucks, TransBridge Bus, Equinox wifi, hotels, etc) and haven't figured out "why" or how to fix this.  I can only assume there is something with the AJAX or the caching of the HTML5 content in chrome or safari that causes this to occur.

> What can a network administrator do to make hotspot authentication work?
>
> What can a developer do with their webpage (I am a developer) to make hotspots always "work" for the end user?

NOTE: I'm not looking for development advice w.r.t coding, I'm looking for an answer from the Network people on what needs to happen on the wire.  Something to the effect of HTTP caching, GET vs POST... or a simple answer that says "AJAX needs the errors handled, and upon an error of XXX then redirect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is usually HTTPS vs HTTP. The TOS/authentication pages are presented by having the router intercept all HTTP requests and reply with a redirect to the TOS/authentication page. However, HTTPS requests can not be intercepted in the same manner without causing a security warning on the user's PC. If you were to change https://www.facebook.com to http://www.facebook.com then the page would come up.

I can only begin to imagine the types of phone calls the hotel would have to deal with if they tampered with an HTTPS connection:

> *Hotel employee:* Front desk, how can I help you?
>
> *Guest:* YOUR WI-FIS IS HACKIN' MAH FACEBOOK!